# the css align-content property does not work with block containers

Tags: html, css

the css align-content property does not work with block containers for example

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="item">this is item</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

> css code

```
.container{
  background-color:yellow;
  width:350px;
  height:200px;
  align-content:center;

}
.item{
  width:100px;
  background-color:gray;
}
```

[edit my code on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/25qudopm/#&togetherjs=T4iTmGtEBa)

> snapshot of css box alignment module description

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioi0k.png)

Answer (score 1):

without `display: flex`, `align-items` and `justify-content` wont' work.

```css
.container{
  background-color:yellow;
  width:350px;
  height:200px;
  display: flex; /* without display: flex, align-items and justify-content wont' work */
  align-items: center; /* to vertically center the content */
  justify-content: center; /* to horizontally center the content */
}
.item{
  width:100px;
  background-color:gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">this is item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: see this image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioi0k.png

Comment: I mean align-content you say justify-content